# Electron builder - how to loadURL for production windows executable build

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I've happily created an angular app and got this to load into Electron via `loadURL`.

The problem is when I build for a production exe file `electron-builder build --windows`
than I get

`__dirname = C:\Users\andrewa\AppData\Local\Temp\1UkY0hucKiKzfrpthFH75bMaiLx\resources\app.asar`

What is the correct way to load `index.html`?
Should I be using `"asar": false` in *electron-builder.json* or is there a way to load this resource?

```
function createWindow() {

    win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    });

    win.loadURL(
      url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, `dist/index.html`), <----------- key line
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true
      }),
    );
}
```

*electron-builder.json*

```
  ...
  "win": {
    "icon": "dist/app/assets/icons",
    "target": ["portable"]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Electron Application Packaging](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging) gives details on the asar file type.

To see what's inside the app.asar file you can run the following
`npx asar list /path/to/app.asar`

Specific to my case I am working outside electron for a http server so I needed to include the following inside *electron-builder.json* which results in these being inside the folder `resources/app.asar.unpacked/` the same folder as the `app.asar` file.

```
  "asarUnpack": [
    "**/dist/procurement-app/*",
    "http/*.js",
    "node_modules/mime/*",
    "node_modules/mime-types/*",
    "node_modules/mime-db/*"
  ],
```